# How many Mad Libs combinations will result when requiring a particular distance between sentences?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

You are randomly filling in a Mad Libs type sentence with words from a set of dictionaries. For instance:

Sentence:
The [COLOR] [ANIMAL] [VERBED] a [NOUN].

Dictionaries:
COLOR: blue white orange
ANIMAL: cat dog bird
VERBED: ate carried became
NOUN: desk cup window

You might end up with sentences such as:
The blue cat ate a desk.
The white dog carried a cup.

You don't want to generate sentences that are too similar however.

These sentences have a distance of 1 and are too similar:
The blue cat ate a desk.
The blue dog ate a desk.

These sentences have a distance of 2, so they are fine:
The blue cat ate a desk.
The white bird ate a desk.

The variables are:
You will generate Mad Libs sentences with `w` unknown words.
For each of the `w` slots, you have a dictionary containing `n` candidate words.
The sentences you generate must have a distance of `d` from all other sentences.

How many unique sentences can you expect to be able to generate?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Sure! I'm a programmer, not a mathematician, and I'm building a discount code system. Rather than giving people codes like hF3kD9h4, we'd rather give them sentences to enter. We need to have enough unique and distant sentences that people can't guess a new discount code based on their old code. The basic combinations problem is easy, but I have no idea where to even start on adding in the distance aspect of this.

Comment: Cool! Good luck with your discount code system.